# Using style file with xcolor

Tags: color, packages

I want to understand what happens when I am using a document with a style file that uses `xcolor`.

Suppose my style file is named `galex.sty` and I have

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolors{Lavender}
```

What happens if in my document I have

```
\usepackage{galex}
```

Would the package `xcolor` be used in the document.  Or is the `\usepackage` only valid for the style file `galex.sty` only?

Comment: You know this would take approximately 20 seconds to test for yourself, right? Anyway, yes, the commands in those packages would be available in the document. It's conventional, however, to use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage` inside a package.

Comment: Right, but I did not want the style file to affect the document, but only for the functionality to be applicable to what I want to do inside the style file.  It has not been long since I started playing to have my own style configuration on some commands.

Comment: If I want to use my package `galex`, should I do `\usepackage{galex}` before `\documentclass`, after, on it does not matter?

Comment: `\usepackage` cannot be used before `\documentclass`; you'll get an error if you try.

It's conventional to use commands containing `@`s in their name if you want to use them only inside the package or document class. This is in part because `@` is treated as a letter in packages and document classes, but not in a document unless explicitly preceded by `\makeatletter`, and so commands with `@` in their names can't be used in a regular document without additional effort.

Comment: @frabjous My mistake, I mean to say `\RequirePackage[` instead.

Comment: As I said earlier, it's conventional not to even use `\RequirePackage` inside documents, but only inside packages and document classes, so in general people don't use it before `\documentclass` either. You'd only do that in a special use case where you had no other choice.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that you may end up with an "Option clash" error when another package, that is loaded after your galex package, also includes/requries the xcolor package.